# Accessing the Item Found by std::find()

Tags: c++, stl, stdlist

I'm trying to teach myself the Standard Template Library. Currently, I'm using `std::find()` to search a `std::list`.

I have code that tests if an item exists and it seems to work just fine.

```
inline bool HasFlag(TCHAR c)
{
    std::list<CCommandLineFlag>::const_iterator it = std::find(m_Flags.begin(), m_Flags.end(), c);
    return (it != m_Flags.end());
}
```

However, this version, which is supposed to return the matching element, does not compile. I get the error message "error C2446: ':' : no conversion from 'int' to 'std::_List_const_iterator<_Mylist>'".

```
inline CCommandLineFlag* GetFlag(TCHAR c)
{
    std::list<CCommandLineFlag>::const_iterator it = std::find(m_Flags.begin(), m_Flags.end(), c);
    return (it != m_Flags.end()) ? it : NULL;
}
```

How can I return a pointer to the instance of the matching item in the second version?

Comment: Tip: if you can use C++11, use `auto` to declare your iterator. `auto it = std::find(m_Flags.begin(), m_Flags.end(), c);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to take the address of the item referenced by the iterator:

```
return (it != m_Flags.end()) ? &(*it) : NULL;
```

Comment: Yes, that seems to be it. I had tried `&*it` at one point, but just wasn't getting it exactly right.

Answer (score 3):

Dereference the iterator, return it's address.

```
return (it != m_Flags.end()) ? &(*it) : NULL;
```

Also change from a const iterator.

```
 std::list<CCommandLineFlag>::iterator it
```

Comment: That gives me the error "error C2446: ':' : no conversion from 'int' to 'const CCommandLineFlag'". I don't see how this would work since, if I dereference it, it's no longer a pointer.

Comment: Yes, after japreiss's suggestion, I had an error about the `const`. And so the change you suggested was needed.

Comment: @juanchopanza Just saw that, and the iterator is const... adjusted the answer accordingly.